# ".." not working in html image directory path

Tags: html, image, path

File Structure:

```
-css
   - home.css
-html
   - index.html
-images
   - banner.png
```

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>myWebsite</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/home.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <img id="banner" src="../images/banner.png" alt="Banner Image"/> <!-- my image won't load? -->
    </header>

    <main> 

    </main>
        
    <footer>

    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

The image doesn't load. And when I try to open the image in another tab from the browser, I get `Cannot GET /images/banner.png`. I think it has to do with the `..` not working, but I could be wrong. It works perfectly fine if I put the image in the same directory as `index.html`. But I don't want to do that as I plan this project to be decently large. I also want to use local image loading. Does anyone know why the image won't load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your diagram is correct .. Your `images` and `css` directories need to be **directly inside** the `html` directory .. IE

```
-html
   - index.html
   - images
       - banner.png
   - css
       - home.css
```

At that point .. There is no need for `..`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/home.css">
<img id="banner" src="/images/banner.png" alt="Banner Image"/>
```

Comment: This works and it could be a possible file structure I could use. But have you found out why I was unable to load the image using the original file structure? If not, then I'll stick with this file structure.

Comment: Your browser cannot access anything "higher" than the "root" `html`  directory .. This is why it wasn't working..  Those directories cannot be accessed .. They MUST be inside the "root" `html` directory.

Answer (score 1):

'../' go up one directory from where I am now
1.find the 'assets/' folder
2.find the 'images' folder
3.find the 'image.jpg' file.
That relative link will only work if your page is in a subfolder in

"http://localhost/abc/def/geh/"

If the location of your page really is

"localhost/asdf/asdf/asdf/asdf/index.php"

(which seems ridiculous) to get to the assets folder relatively you would have to go all the way to the root.

'../../../../abc/deh/geh/assets/images/image.jpg;

Alternatively you could use a base tag in your head tag to make the URL in the actual src attribute more friendly.